# Knockout JS how to bind observable of object html bind

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, binding

I need to bind to cshtml view a ko.observable which holds an object defined by me. To clarify let's go with a small piece of code:

ViewModel:

```
define('vm.test',
['ko', 'model'],
function(ko, model) {

    var
        myObject = ko.observable(new model.MyModel()),

        someFunction = function() {
            // Here goes some code which obtains object data
            myObject.property1 = data.test;
            myObject.property2 = data.test2;
            myObject.property3 = data.test3;
        };


    return {
        myObject: myObject,
        someFunction: someFunction 
    };
});
```

Model:

```
define('model.myModel',
['ko'],
function (ko) {

    var
        MyModel= function () {
            var self = this;
            self.property1= ko.observable();
            self.property2= ko.observable();
            self.property3= ko.observable();
            self.isNullo = false;
            return self;
        };

    MyModel.Nullo = new MyModel()
        .property1('')
        .property2('')
        .property3('');
    MyModel.Nullo.isNullo = true;

    return MyModel;
});
```

And what I want to achieve is to bind each property of myObject to separate, let's say,  in HTML. I have tried to do this in several ways, but unfortunately without any success. **Does anyone have an idea how to bind such an object to separate spans?**

What I have already tried and did not work for me:

Approach 1:

```
    <div data-bind="with: myObject">
        <span data-bind="text: $data.property1"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.property2"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.property3"></span>
    </div>
```

Approach 2:

```
    <span data-bind="text: myObject.property1"></span>
```

Approach 3:

```
    <span data-bind="text: myObject().property1"></span>
```

And none of those works.
The binding with the view model works, as well as the whole structure, since other properties (simple observables or observableArrays) I use in the vm are binded without any problems to the view. What is more, if I write to console the content of myObject from within the view model, it is filled with the values I wanted. However, the values are not assigned to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps changing this:

```
myObject = ko.observable(new model.MyModel()),
```

to this:

```
myObject = new model.MyModel(),
```

**EDIT:**

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Yyzp/1).

**EDIT 2:**

Please note that you cannot update your observables like this:

```
myObject.property1 = data.test;
```

but instead, you need to make a function call:

```
myObject.property1(data.test);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, this does not work as well. Or perhaps I do not know how to properly call it from the html side? I have tried with all the three approaches I presented above.

Comment: You are doing something else wrong then. Please see the fiddle as a proof of concept.

Comment: Actually, you are correct. If I create the object of type MyModel during the initialization and assign the value of its field in that place it all works perfectly (I've just checked), I mean: myObject= new model.MyModel().property1('343434')
and then binding to span as data-bind="text: myObject.property1"

The problem occurs when I want to change the value of initialized previously variable - it does not update.

Comment: That was the case :) silly me.. and proper binding is div data-bind="with: myObject" and inside of it spans with direct binding to names of myObject properties. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use data-bind = "with:Modelobject" in the parent HTML DOM this will make each of your object property observable